# IPtables command to block specific port for certain ip

Tags: networking, iptables, router

I want to block certain services such as ftp, telnet, http for a certain ip address. What command will I execute in order to achieve this. The only command I have tried is

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10 -j DROP
```

but I want specific ports only not everything.

Comment: You are developing somewhat of a debris field of abandoned questions. The answer from @muru below is correct, you should accept it to close this one.

Comment: @DougSmythies the odd thing is, OP did accept it once, then unaccepted it the next day. Never said why.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the port using `--dport`:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP #http
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 10.10.10.10 -p tcp --dport 21 -j DROP #ftp
```

Comment: I got this response: `iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "--dport"`

Comment: You also need to specify the protocol type - `tcp` or `udp` for port addressing to work (port numbers are a specific TCP and UDP feature, it is not part of the IP protocol). I edited the answer to fix.